# How do you put a restriction on a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make an add and remove button that has an input that has a text type and it show numbers. The add and remove button work and it will show positive numbers and negative also. I don't want it to show negative numbers. How do I make it so it can't go lower than 0? Also I do not want the input to have a number type.

Here is my code:

```
<button onclick="add();">ADD</button>
<button onclick="remove();">REMOVE</button>
<input type="text" id="inc">

<script>
var i = 0;
    function add() {
        if(i >= 0) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
        } else {
            i = 0;
            document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
        }

    }
        function remove() {
        i--;
        document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
    }
        </script>
```

Comment: Ensure the value is in range before using it using `if` statements.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
var i = 0;
    function add() {
        if(i >= 0) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
        } else {
            i = 0;
            document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
        }

    };
        function remove() {
        i--;
        if(i >= 0){
        document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="add();">ADD</button>
<button onclick="remove();">REMOVE</button>
<input type="text" id="inc">
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But now how do I get the add button to have a maximum of 24. and if it is on 24 and you try to add any more it takes you back to 0 and just keeps doing this if you try to add over 24?

Comment: if(i >= 0 && i < 25){

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

Comment: I used this in my code and now i cant remove at all... it is probably because it is being told to add until 24 is reached and go to 0 if above 24.

Answer (score 0):

in the same way where you have set a constraint in the `add()` function, do the same thing for the `remove()` function by doing the processing only if `i-1 >= 0` :

```
 function remove() {        
    if(i-1 >= 0) {
        i--;           
        document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `remove` function so that it doesn't decrement lower than zero

```
function remove() {
    i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0;
    document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers already suggested, you can also use `Math.max()` to ensure the value never goes below 0.

Replace `i--` with `i = Math.max(i - 1, 0)`